# Deleting a group of users with the option to reassign one or more users to different groups without using a popup?

Tags: website-design, user-expectation, user-centered-design, deletion, software

We are developing a system where users have to be assigned to a group of permissions. Currently, the problem lies in deletion.

The desired functionality is when an admin user deletes one group that has users assigned to it, they will have the option to reassign those users to other groups before deleting the requested group. The options will be either reassign all the users to one different group or assign each user separately.

What is the best way to handle this case without the use of popups?

Comment: Do you have any mockups of ideas you've considered?

Comment: i saw this mockup here:
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14644/how-should-i-handle-deleting-a-role-when-there-are-still-users-with-it-assigned/14674#14674

but i'm trying to avoid pop up. thought of leading the user to a table with the current users associated with the group he want to delete, and let him reassign one by one or all

but i am not that good in UX/UI so i need some advice or comments

Comment: i want to make it clearer:
the user go to the main screen of groups and select to delete a group
on this stage he see that there are users associated with the group. i thought about redirect him to the users screen of the system with a table filtered with the associated users to that group and then let him reassign

how does it sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two flows here.

- Delete a group
- Reassign a user

It appears to me that you are trying to fit these two operations in a single action. I would avoid that. I would rather design a system which has two separate operations. Delete group and reassign user.

If an admin tries to delete a group which has users associated to it, I'd notify the admin to reassign or any other possible operation which decouples the user from the group. This notification will end the flow of that user action. (*I might also think of not giving a delete option for a group which has users, but for that I need more information on the system and user comfort level of the system*).

The admin user then may decide to open that group see the users in that group and individually or collectively perform actions on them. Those would be different flows triggered by separate action.

About designing the screens, we will need more information as to how you plan to show these relationships currently, how many groups are possible, how many users per group are possible, can user be part of more than group, etc. I'd request you to add mock ups of your current approach, and this forum might be able to give more effective feedback.

Comment: as for you questions: 1. user can be assign to only one group 2. max groups 15 top 3. users per group is unlimited, but i believe not more than 15

currently on the group view i present the user how many active users assigned to the group and have a link that direct to the users screens.
i understand your point, but i thought that it will be more user friendly if i will combine there two flow into one instead to interrupting the user in the middle of one
isn't a good approach? otherwise, i will keep the two flows separately :/

Comment: A single flow is chaining of actions. If this is very normal in rest of your application, and your application is targeted for power users, I might be okay with it, but it almost always a bad idea. So what about having a left side navigation with groups selection and right side grid with the users of that group? You can do something like this. It is very primitive and just to give you an idea. http://i.imgur.com/lWQQg21.png

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this without an extra UI flow, have a default group that new users, and users who had their group deleted automatically go to. And when an admin deletes a group, you just move all those users to the default group.